# d3js - How to use the `this` keyword or what is the alternate?

Tags: d3.js

When user click on the `legend` i am hiding and showing the `path`. it works. But as well i would like to keep the `legend` as semi-transparent, when the `path` was hidden.

for that, I am trying to add the style to the `legend` using the `this` key word but it's not working.

what is the correct way to do this? her is my code :

```
legends.on('click', function(d, i) {
    var path = d3.select("#" + d.name);
    var visibility = path.style('opacity');
    path.style("opacity", visibility == 1 ? 0 : 1);

    if (!visibility) {

        d3.select(this).style('opacity', 0.5);//not working!
        this.style('opacity', 0.5);//not working!

    }

});
```

**update**

tried this way still not works:

```
legends.forEach(function(group) {

    var legend = group;

    legend.on('click', function(d, i) { //throws error

        var path = d3.select("#" + d.name);
        var visibility = path.style('opacity');
        path.style("opacity", visibility == 1 ? 0 : 1);

        console.log(legend);

    });

})
```

**update**

On click consoled `this` - is :
[image: console]

Comment: Could you post a JSFiddle / JSBin / ... showing the issue ?

Comment: this is not so easy to reproduce in    fiddle, since the scenario require multiple dependents

Comment: Could you output the `d` by console, and check the bundled data?

Comment: @DavidGuan - d is updated with my question

Comment: @3gwebtrain sorry, I'm expressed clearly. `console.log` the `d` in `.on('click', function(d, i)`, to make sure the selection is correct one.

Comment: could you explain what 'legends' is and how you create it

Comment: @DavidGuan when, on click the mouse, i have captured the `this` in console. that's exactly giving my `legend` what i appended - see my question console info added

Comment: in the screenshot you posted, legend has the style you want it to have

Comment: For me this works on chrome and FF are you trying on IE?

Comment: @Cyril - if you don't mine, can you share you code through any of the fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to add click event to legends group.

You should add click event when you are appending the elements. I am adding example with dummy data. [Here is filddle](https://jsfiddle.net/murli2308/be795wd1/1/). Hope this helps you.

**HTML**

```
<div id="chartArea"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
svg {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

**Javscritpt**

```
//appending svg to div and adding width and height
var svg = d3.select("#chartArea").append("svg");
svg.attr({
    'width' : 350,
  'height': 150
});

//dummy data
var data = [{name: "legend1"}, {name: "legend2"}];

//appending group
var groupSelection = svg.append('g');

//appending legends
var legendSelection = groupSelection.selectAll('text')
                .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .attr("x", 10)
        .attr("y", function(d, i) { return (i+1) * 15;})
        .text(function(d) {return d.name;})
        .on('click', legendClickFunction);

//click event handler
function legendClickFunction(d, i) {
        console.log(this);
        //adding color to text using this selection
        d3.select(this).attr("fill", "red");
}
```